# Configurar gtkmm en codeblocks

Tags: c++, gtk

No encuentro la forma de configurar code blocks para usar gtkmm, instalé esto con la terminal de 
MSYS:

To install the one targeting x86_64:
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc

Similarly, you need to install the gtkmm libs:
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtkmm3

You will probably also want pkg-config:
pacman -S pkg-config

Agregué C:\msys64\mingw64 a el path

Después de eso abrí codeblocks, creé un proyecto y ejecuté el código de prueba:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv);

        Gtk::Window window;
        window.set_default_size(600,400);

        return app->run(window);
}
```

Busqué tutoriales para configurar gtkmm en codeblocks y aparecieron cosas 
parecidas a esto, hice todas pero no ha funcionado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]